# Strange C++ behaviour involving iostream and wstring

Tags: c++, iostream, wstring

I have two files, `my_program.cpp` and its header `my_program.h`.

`my_program.cpp` contains *only* this:

```
#include "my_program.h"
using namespace std;
```

`my_program.h` contains a pointer to a function which returns a `wstring`, as follows:

```
using namespace std;
typedef wstring (*my_function)(wstring, int, int, int, int);
```

The program doesn't compile in this state (stops at typedef... saying that ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wstring' with no type) but if I add `#include <iostream>` before `#include "my_program.h"` in the .cpp file, the program miraculously compiles.

Why does this happen? I just hope I didn't make a foolish mistake and I'm now going to be laughed at.

Comment: I can't fully read this typedef declaration, but... where is your new typename in that typedef?

Comment: Have you `#include <string>` in `my_porgram.h`?

Comment: @Frizi `my_function` is the name of the typedef. It's a pointer to a function returning wstring and having wstring, int, int ... as parametres.

Comment: `my_function` is *not* "a pointer to a function which returns a wstring".

Comment: `my_function` is an alias for the type `pointer to function returning a wstring ...`. It is not itself a pointer to anything, but can be used to define a pointer of that type: `my_function f;`, or a parameter of that type: `some_function(my_function f);`, etc.

Comment: @Robᵩ yes I knew that, I just didn't bother to explain.

Comment: @JerryCoffin So the defined type name is "my_function", which is an alias to a pointer to a function. Thank You for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should include `<string>`.

From the sound of things, your compiler's `<iostream>` happens to include `<string>`, so it works, but on a different compiler it may not. C++ allows a standard header to include other standard headers, but doesn't require it. In some cases, you get only a declaration of the class, so some things work, and others don't.

At least in my experience, this is also an issue that's likely to change from one version of a compiler to the next, so even if you don't intend to port to anything else, your code may quit working just due to a seemingly trivial upgrade unless you include the right header.

Comment: My bad. I should've known that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add `#include <iostream>`, the compiler has no idea what `wstring` is -- hence the error

After you include the iostream header, (which defines `std::wstring` -- possibly via other headers it includes), the compiler knows what `wstring` refers to and can properly parse the `typedef`.

One thing to keep in mind is that the compiler only cares about what's called the compilation unit (.cpp files), not the headers; the headers come into play when a compilation unit includes them (think of verbatim copy-paste).  Therefore you can include `iostream` (or as others pointed out `<string>`) anywhere before the `typedef`, to make it work -- from this perspective, including it before the header counts the same as including it at the first line of the header.

It is generally a good idea, however, to make headers as self consistent as possible (so in your case include the relevant headers in your header, instead of the .cpp), so the includers do not need to remember what other headers to include as well to make it work as intended.

Comment: I moved `using namespace std;` before `#include "my_program.h"` in the cpp and it's the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's the same", but the `using namespace std;` declaration "lifts" everything in the `std` namespace into global namespace, so you don't have to prefix everything with `std` (e.g. `wstring` instead of `std::wstring`) -- it should not make a difference wheter it is in the .cpp or the header in this case as long as it is after the `include<string>` and before the `typedef`